# Building a blog with JSON and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this project to build a jQuery based blog with JSON/HTML/CSS/LESS & Javascript.

My problem is that every post should come from a JSON file and I have no clue how to get it in to the actual blog.

JSON file:

```
{ 
    "post1" : {
            "title":  "My day",
            "content" :  "blalbvblblblblblblallksdlmalmdksdkasd",
            "date" :  "12/0-16",
            "author" :  "robert",
            "image" :  "../blogg/img.jpg"
    },
    "post2" : {
            "title":  "This right here",
            "content" :  "blalbvblblblblblblallksdlmalmdksdkasd",
            "date" :  "12/0-16",
            "author" :  "robert",
            "image" :  "../blogg/img.jpg"
    },
    "post4" : {
            "title":  "Min vackra",
            "content" :  "blalbvblblblblblblallksdlmalmdksdkasd",
            "date" :  "12/0-16",
            "author" :  "klara",
            "image" :  "../blogg/img.jpg"
    }
}
```

I have tried using the`$getJSON` method but no progress.

So basically what I need is to get the stuff from the JSON file in to a `div` in my index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   url: "myJSONFile.json",
}).done(function(resp){
   for(var p in resp){
     if(!resp.hasOwnProperty(p)) continue;
     var title = resp[p].title;
     var content = resp[p].content;
     // etc...
   }
});
```

use jquery's $.ajax method

Comment: This worked and i succesfully loaded my json file but i have an unexpected property (p) in the console and i dont understand why... I have learnt now that i should should use append to make the div  but I should be able to just write a new ""blog post" in the JSON file and then it should automatically load it in to the page, and this i dont have any clue on how to do. Sorry that i suck on programming :(

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once.

Comment: My mistake "name" should have been "p".. thanks for catching that i updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Function that reads contents from that file should look like that:

```
$.getJSON( "urlToFile.json" )
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        var title = item.title;
        var content = item.content;
        var date = item.date;
        var author = item.author;
        var image = item.image;

        // Here you can create each blog post and add append it into your blog

        // example:
        var title = $("<div/>", {
          "class": "blog-title",
          "text": title
        }).appendTo(container);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Is your requirement to use jQuery or is it ok for you to use frameworks such as AngularJS? you can basically use jQuery to this as well by declaring variables containing your HTML code and then by using $("#yourdiv").html() put in your variable's content into your layout. But it all depends on your requirements, there are great frameworks out there helping you with this a lot. E.g. AngularJS, KnockoutJS, etc in which you bind your HTML layout to your javascript - using MVVM techniques.

- AngularJS: https://angularjs.org/
- KnockoutJS: http://knockoutjs.com/

And then the question, is the JSON stored in your filesystem on the server, if this is the case you need some sort of API anyhow, that can access the JSON or you open up your server to access the files.

JQuery and all javascript frameworks will need to connect to your server in some way, since you write it's a blog you are trying to code here.

Comment: question is tagged jquery. there is no angular tag. dont tell people to use libraries for no reason...

Comment: Well... I definitely do not agree with you... First of all, I was asking if there is a requirement of using jquery... the other thing is... jquery makes it hard to maintain the layout of the html being produced by jquery... ugly code, not really readable for everybody. So, for me recommending libraries, that makes our life easier, is self-explanatory. Especially when it comes to creating a blog, which will change over time  (at least in most cases, design changes...). If the js contains snippets generating html, it can be a difficult task to change it...